# Entity Framework Pluralization Concern

Tags: entity-framework

This is a two part question:

1)  What is the advantage of pluralizing other than having model respective tables names implying that they contain a collection of entity records?

2) Pluralizing is a very intricate art, and is sensitive to language localization. When I created an Entity called **Schema**, EF yielded a table called **Schemata**.
There is a major problem with this.  Primarily, a developer would need to know that the plural of Schema is not Schemas, but the aforementioned.  Also, this means that EF maintains some sort of a linguistic dictionary which explicitely dictates pluralization of words, and this can lead to unexpected results..

PS: Ok..., lets have the SO antifa-blm-nazis vote to close my question because it doesn't meet some guidelines, and because they have nothing better to do with their lives, and this commentary is really offensive(albeit true to life)!

Answer (score 0):

Every Entity Framework entity I've ever created I have control over the pluralized version of the name, so I'm not sure what the issue is. You don't have to accept the suggested pluralization. The pluralization is useful in following connections to child entities and their collections, so there is a reason to have them in the first place. Use common sense in creating pluralized names that have the broadest, most easily grasped meaning.